# question about copying

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a file called pam.sql which is in desktop.

I want that file to be copied into mysql. And when I given the command `show databases;` it should show pam.sql file.

Comment: My question-detection senses have failed.

Comment: There's not even a question mark in there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to import th sql file into mysql, if so please check: [Using mysql in Batch Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)